# Jetty_run error java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.annotation.meta.When not present

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Project successfuly runs in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1 with JDK 1.8.0_221
When our new staff-mates tryed to start it in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1 they both get en error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postgresqlEntityManager' defined in com.configuration.PostgresqlConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.annotation.meta.When not present
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That helped us:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
>         <version>3.0.2</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```